# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist error for base template

Tags: django, templates, template-inheritance

I learnt about Django template inheritance and was working on it.

I made a `base_post_login.html` template in the same directory as other templates.

and type `{% extends "base_post_login.html" %}` as the first line in in a child template.

But when the child template is rendered through back-end the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error is raised.

this is settings.py(relevant part):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

all templates are rendered properly if it does not extend and parent template.

What should I do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain how you structuring your application and mention where your templates folder located...

Comment: looks like your child template and `base_post_login.html` are not in same directory. And you set `APP_DIRS` to `True`. Do your template files exist under different apps' folders? If so, you may need to define those solders in `DIRS` option.

Comment: @alix He said >  in the same directory as other templates

Comment: I know that.. But something is not clear and missing in question. The code should work with this structure. @Saksow

Comment: check my answer update, it may be that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using Django [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends) the wrong way, it should take the parent template name so do this:

`{% extends "base.html" %}`

EDIT

OK I see, you should use the template path like you do when you render your other templates:

Let's say you render like this "templates/child_page.html" then you should extend the same way `{% extends "templates/base.html" %}`

Comment: sorry for that..it was a typo..fixed now..it is base_post_login.html

Comment: oh yeah..this worked ..thanks..i thought that it is not required as both the templates are in the same directory but they are rendered through views.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter where each template is, you have to refer to it using your template path, the same thing you do in views you do it in templates. Cheers!

Comment: The edit with the proper path really helped! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to settings.py

your templates settings should look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
}, ]
```

make sure BASE_DIR is also defined